# Prove equality (binomial-coefficients)

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{i=k}^{n-l} {i \choose k}{n-i \choose l} = {n+1 \choose k+l+1}$$
I understand how to prove this using that equality:
$$\sum_{i=k}^{n-l} {i \choose k}{n-i \choose l} = {n \choose k+l} + \sum_{i=k}^{n-l-1} {i \choose k}{n-i-1 \choose l }$$
But I came to it with the help of my intuition, if there is a strict solution, I just want to know about it.

Comment: Off point: Alternative set theory approach is to consider choosing $~(k + l + 1)~$ seats from a row of $~(n+1)~$ seats.  From the left, chosen seat $~(k+1)~$ will have $~k~$ chosen seats to its left and $~l~$ chosen seats to its right.  Then, the possible positions of chosen seat $~(k+1)~$ is seat number $~(k+1)~$ through seat number $~(n+1-l),~$ inclusive.  For each choice $~(i+1)~$ of chosen seat $~(k+1),~$ the number of ways of having $~k~$ chosen seats to its left and $~l~$ chosen seats to its right is $~\displaystyle \binom{i}{k} \times \binom{[n+1] - [i+1]}{l}.$

Comment: thanks your tips really helped me